# Unable to save as PDF from VBA in mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to save a range from a sheet as PDF through VBA. Following is the code that I have written.

```
Sheets("PO Format").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$6 : $J$42"
Sheets("PO Format").Range("B6:J42").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Sheets("User Settings").Range("B15") & "/" & Sheets("PO Format").Range("F7"), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

The weird thing is that it is working fine on one system and I able to save it at the mentioned path and then also send out a mail, but while testing it on another system I am getting the error as "Error while printing". Completely clueless. Can anyone help??

Comment: Does the target machine have a PDF print driver?  Can you manually print to PDF on this machine?

Comment: @destination-data yes I am able to do it manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Mac Office 2016 Microsoft have to deal with Apple’s sandbox requirements due to which VBA needs permission to access folders and this is not prompted while trying to save via VBA instead it gives an error. But there are a few places on Mac that one can use to let the code do what it needs to do without user interaction.

one such path is /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office
This folder gets created when Office 2016 is installed.

So I saved the PDF to this folder, moved it to the desired location and it is working fine now.

For more details and the code go through http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that Excel SaveAsPDFandXPS addin is installed, if available for Mac then you should be able to find it on Microsoft site,it available for free. Install it then the code should work just fine.

Comment: Couldn't find any such addin for excel 2016 and manually I am able to save it as pdf, but through the code I get the error while printing error.

Comment: The addin is for 2007. If you are using 2016 then no need to get it