# Saving sheet as PDF on PC and Mac

Tags: excel, macos, pdf

In trying to get a simple function as "Save active sheet to PDF" running on an Apple Mac Office 2016 I came across the code below.

However, whilst it runs perfectly on Windows it fails on Mac with a "Print - Error while printing" message followed by Run-time error 1004: Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

I have tried many variations but none seem to work.

```
Sub CreatePDF()
Dim wksSheet As Worksheet
Dim TheOS As String

TheOS = Application.OperatingSystem

If InStr(1, TheOS, "Windows") > 0 Then
  Set wksSheet = ActiveSheet
        wksSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Sheet1 on Windows", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
                False
        Exit Sub

Else
  Set wksSheet = ActiveSheet
        wksSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                ThisWorkbook.Path & ":" & "Sheet1 on Mac", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
                False
        Exit Sub
   End If
```

Comment: Can you try replacing "Sheet1 on Mac" (in the filename) with "S1M"? I wonder if it'd make any difference.

Comment: Alas no change. Still get the exact error message after changing 'Sheet1 on Mac' to 'S1M'...

Comment: Is the sheet name _Worksheet? Can you try renaming that, too, to simply Worksheet?

Comment: I think the problem is described (together with a workaround) here (first answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148305/unable-to-save-as-pdf-from-vba-in-mac

Comment: If I change the above code and comment out line the Set wkSheet line, and change the wkSheet.Export... to ActiveSheet.Export..., and remove the line feed '_' character the run-time error changes to 'Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: I have looked at the work around as described by Ron de Bruin but still no luck. I can't believe that a simple bit of code is stumping people...