# Save range of cells to PDF at ThisWorkbook.Path

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have this macro that saves to a defined path which is not useful since multiple people will be using the file.

```
Sub SavetoPdf()
'
' SavetoPdf Macro
' To Save to PDF Details
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    Range("E31:I54").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "/Users/Me/Desktop/"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "/Users/Me/Desktop/" & Range("G41").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
End Sub
```

I thought to save to ThisWorkbook.Path and modified the above.

```
Sub SavetoPdf()
    ' Saves active sheet as PDF file.

    Dim Name As String

    Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Range("G41").Value & ".pdf"

    Range("E31:I54").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=Name, _
        Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

I am on a Mac.

I get

> Error on Printing

and the debugger highlights this code:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=Name, _
  Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _ 
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  What happens when you run it?  Are you on a Mac?

Comment: Yes I am on a Mac. I get an Error on Printing dialog box and the debugger highlights this code:

Comment: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=Name, _
        Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Comment: Is "Name" variable showing the correct result?

Comment: " I get an Error " - what error do you get?

Comment: I get "Print - Error while Printing"

Comment: Please check out this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148305/unable-to-save-as-pdf-from-vba-in-mac), I know this might be wrong try changing "/" to"\".

Comment: Or you can try this path separator ":"

Comment: I tried the different separators. No luck. Not surprised since I am able to get it to work with a defined location. Alternatively, I would be happy if someone could supply the code to let the user select the save location. That would be fine as well

Answer (score 0):

You title reads that you want to PDF a "Range" of cells. Is that what is not working for you?

```
Sub SavetoPdf()
' Saves active sheet as PDF file.

    Dim Name As String

    Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Range("G41").Value & ".pdf"

    Range("E31:I54").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Name, _
                                         Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
                                         IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: The range of cells is fine, its getting it to save in the same location as the workbook that is the challenge. I can't hard code a location since this file will have many users

Answer (score 0):

Modified @Davesexel code: Tested on mock data and saved no problem.

```
Dim rng As Range   
Dim Name As String

Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G41") 'Change worksheet to your needs

Name = rng.Value
Range("E31:I54").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Name & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: I am still getting an runtime error '1004' - Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object 'Range' failed... Sorry if this is frustrating I'm not a developer and appreciate the patience and suport.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see the Mac comment only tested for PC.