# "Run-time error 1004" with VBA code initiated PDF export

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export a sheet to PDF, but when I run the code I keep getting a 1004 error.

I believe that it is linked to the folder path to the save destination. I've tried defining the file path in different ways but still get the error.

This code is supposed to pull a part of the file name from cell B1 and the file path from the location of the worksheet. The PDF is supposed to be saved to the location of the worksheet. I'm fairly new to VBA. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code

```
Sub ExportAsPDFTest()

Dim Name As String
Dim Preface As String


Name = Cells(1, "B").Value
Preface = "PreR Summer 2019 - "

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Preface & Name & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=1, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: You should see it now.

Comment: You'll need a backslash between the `Path` and `Preface`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a backslash `\` (or `/` if you're on Mac) after `ActiveWorkbook.Path`. You can use `Application.PathSeparator` so it will work on both:

```
Sub ExportAsPDFTest()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Preface As String

    Name = Cells(1, "B").Value
    Preface = "PreR Summer 2019 - "

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Preface & Name & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=1, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this code but it still gives me the error "Error while printing. Run-time error 1004. Application-defined or object-defined error." I'm using a mac. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I tried `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Preface & Name & ".pdf"` and got /Users/elijah/Desktop/PreR Summer 2019 - name.pdf

Comment: That's correct. It means that it must be for some other reasons. I executed the code on my Windows Excel right now and it works, so it must be something Mac related...

Comment: Is it possibly similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148305/unable-to-save-as-pdf-from-vba-in-mac)?

Comment: The file path that it outputs is correct but the file is not saving to that location. Even if I set the `Filename:="test.pdf"` it still gives the error.

Comment: I moved the worksheet to `/Users/elijah/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/` and was able to successfully export the PDF with the desired name. Though this solution works, it seems like there should be a better solution to this permission problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe someone can can come up with something, but I suggest you to open a new question for this. In the mean time, if you found this answer helpful, please consider accepting it. Thx!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please add msgbox Activeworkbook.path to check your save path, you need add one more "\"

Comment: So just to clarify: Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\\" & Preface & Name & ".pdf", _